# Getting Error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" while formatting date string

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting

I am really confused and probably I am completely blind currently.

I get a DateTime from an external source like this and as string:

```
"9/29/2022 5:32:36 AM"
```

Whend I parse and format the string like this:

```
DateTime.Parse("9/29/2022 5:32:36 AM").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt")
```

I get the error

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

When I use this DateTime:

```
"29/9/2022 5:32:36 AM"
```

The parsing and formatting works correctly

I thought that the formatting is able to handle "month/day" thing but obviously this is not the case.

What do I miss? Do I need to add Culture here somehow?

It would be great if one can put me into the right direction

Comment: Perhaps `.Parse("yourdate", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: Did you try `ParseExact()` instead?

Comment: You need to include seconds : ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt"

Comment: .Parse("yourdate", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) did the job, thx!

The other two solutions gave me the same error, thx anyway :)